# Facebook API, libGDX cross platform

Tags: android, scala, libgdx, cross-platform

So I have been wondering. Is it possible to use the Facebook API with libGDX that it runs on Android and Desktop? If it is not well, everything cannot work out, now can it? 
Thank you for reading this reaaaaaaly beginner question, but I am new to the facebook API(have not even started tbh, I was searching for a cross-platform way of doing things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to use Facebook API with LibGDX.

LibGDX is a cross platform framework so you've to write platform specific code for facebook. Take a look about platform specific code in libgdx:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

---

Also you should check,

[gdx-facebook](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook) : A libGDX extension providing cross-platform support for Facebook Graph API.

Comment: But gdx-facebook says it 
Desktop(for development only). Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Yes **Desktop** is for development only, mostly we use desktop module for testing our development progress, you should talk to his maintainer if you want to use in release version. like regarding breakage/bug for desktop.